# Symfony Propel Many-To-Many Add

Tags: database, symfony1, many-to-many, generator, propel

I have e functional Symfony Project. I need to add a Many-To-Many relationships in the project.

I have jobs table and cities table. How can I add this relantionships using Generator (I dont want to alter existing data)? 
I will use this relationship in Jobs forms (add,edit,list) to assign multiple Cities to a Job.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a cross reference table sitting between your Jobs and Cities:

```
<table name="job_city" isCrossRef="true">
  <column name="job_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" />
  <column name="city_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" />

  <foreign-key foreignTable="job">
    <reference local="job_id" foreign="id" />
  </foreign-key>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="city">
    <reference local="city_id" foreign="id" />
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

After regenerating you will have a new set of classes: JobCity, JobCityQuery, and JobCityPeer to use. You can add a new job to a city like so:

```
$job = new Job();
// add job info ...
$job->save();
$city = CityQuery::create()->findOneByName("Austin");
$city->addJob($job);
$city->getJobs(); // returns PropelObjectCollection of Job objects
```